# Como criar um shell script que coloca um echo no começo de cada linha em um arquivo

Tags: script, bash, shell-script, shell

Preciso criar um script que inseri o comando echo no inicio de cada linha do arquivo e no final >> blocodenotas, por exemplo

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l
uname -a
netstat -tunap
```

quero um script que transforme nisso:

```
echo "#!/bin/bash >> log"
echo "ls -l" >> log"
echo "uname -a" >> log" 
echo "netstat -tunap >> log"
```

Comment: Com o comando `cat` é possível gravar um bloco de instruções em um arquivo utilizando o simples recurso `document here`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o utilitário `awk` para resolver seu problema com apenas uma linha, veja só:

```
$ awk '{ print "echo \"" $0 "\" >> log"  }' script.sh > saida.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Com sed também é possivel:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/echo \"/;s/$/ >> log\"/'  arquivo
```